# Smoother ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have a set of unstructured data (downloadable from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BF3uq4uOlAmk-ybkpjSyYH7FuI0X5RkH/view?usp=sharing). When attempting to plot them, I get a rough "spiky" result.

```
ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Is there any way to smoothen the plotted surface?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether another ways suitable you request？

```
GradientFittedMesh[data, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

```
ReconstructionMesh[data, Method -> Automatic]
```

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 8, Mesh -> None, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for but still much better than my attempt! Thank you :)